# Problem with \pspicture in a simple plain TeX code

Tags: pstricks, plain-tex, pspicture

Just writing the following very simple program I had some problems. I use to write in plain TeX and in this case I tried to make a picture with PSTricks and first of all sized it with \pspicture. The program is:

```
\input pstricks
\pspicture (0,0)(5,5)
\endpspicture
\bye
```

but when I compiled with TeX, I encountered the following error:

```
Command Line:   tex.exe --src --interaction=errorstopmode "figura.tex"
Startup Folder: C:\Users\MT\Documents\TeX

This is TeXk, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2015/W32TeX) (preloaded format=tex)
 Source specials enabled.
(./figura.tex (c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
we are running tex and have to define some LaTeX commands ...
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex
2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvtxhdr.tex
2005/02/22 v1.1 xkeyval TeX header (HA))))
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.tex
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-lists.tex))
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.code.tex))
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.tex
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigonometric.code
.tex)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.random.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.comparison.code.te
x) (c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.code.tex)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integerarithmetics
.code.tex))) (c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
`PSTricks' v2.64b  <2015/14/11> (tvz)
(c:/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
! Undefined control sequence.
\endpspicture ...z@ \box \pst@hbox \else \fboxsep 
                                                  =0pt \fbox {\rule [-\pst@s...
l.5 \endpspicture

? x
No pages of output.
Transcript written on figura.log.

_____________________________________________________________________

 TeX Compilation Report (Pages: 0)

 Errors: 1   Warnings: 0   Bad Boxes: 0
_____________________________________________________________________
```

What's the problem?

Comment: Works in texlive 2016 but not in texlive 2015.

Comment: That was a bug, simply update your TeX distribution or use `pstricks.tex` from http://comedy.dante.de/~herbert/texnik/tex/generic/pstricks/

Answer (score 3):

Let's see the relevant code in `pstricks.tex` as found in TeX Live 2014, near the end (with `[...]` I denote code that's unimportant)

```
\def\endpspicture{%
  [...]
  \if@star\setbox\pst@hbox=\hbox{\clipbox@@\z@}\fi%
  \leavevmode\box\pst@hbox%
  \endgroup%
  \psset[pstricks]{shift=0}% reset value
}
```

The same in TeX Live 2015

```
\def\endpspicture{%
  [...]
  \if@star\setbox\pst@hbox=\hbox{\clipbox@@\z@}\fi
  \leavevmode\ifdim\overfullrule=\z@\box\pst@hbox\else
  \fboxsep=0pt
  \fbox{\rule[-\pst@shift]{0pt}{\ht\pst@hbox}\rule{\wd\pst@hbox}{0pt}}\fi
  \endgroup%
  \psset[pstricks]{shift=0}% reset value
}
```

Here's the version with TeX Live 2016

```
\def\endpspicture{%
  [...]
  \if@star\setbox\pst@hbox=\hbox{\clipbox@@\z@}\fi
  \leavevmode
  \ifdim\overfullrule=\z@
    \box\pst@hbox
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname @latexerr\endcsname\relax
      \box\pst@hbox
    \else  %    do we have LaTeX? 
      \fboxsep=0pt
      \fbox{\rule[-\pst@shift]{0pt}{\ht\pst@hbox}\rule{\wd\pst@hbox}{0pt}}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \endgroup
  \psset[pstricks]{shift=0}% reset value
}
```

As you can clearly see, if `\overfullrule` is set to a value larger than 0pt (which is the default in plain TeX), some LaTeX code is executed when one uses TeX Live 2015.

Solution: update your TeX distribution.

If this is not possible, set `\overfullrule` to 0pt

```
\input pstricks

\overfullrule=0pt

\pspicture (0,0)(5,5)
\endpspicture
\bye
```

Alternatively,

```
\input pstricks

\catcode`@=11
\def\fboxsep#1\fi{\box\pst@hbox\fi}
\catcode`@=12

\pspicture (0,0)(5,5)
\endpspicture
\bye
```

Comment: Thanks for answers. I tried with `\overfullrule=0pt`and it worked.