# Psvectorian not working when \overfullrule is > 0

Tags: psvectorian

When using TexLive 2015 on Ubuntu, I find that all psvectorian graphics are replaced by an empty rectangle when I set \overfullrule to some nonzero value.  For instance:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{psvectorian}
%\overfullrule=2cm
\begin{document}
BEFORE
\psvectorian{12}
AFTER
\end{document}
```

will produce what I'd like to see:

[image: normal output]

but if I uncomment "\overfullrule=2cm", this is the borked result:

[image: output with graphic removed]

The same file works fine on OS X with MaxTeX 2014. In all cases, I see nothing in the logs that reports any error: no "Overfull hbox".

Any clues?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with MacTeX 2016. As far as I remember, the version of `pstricks` in TeX Live 2015 had a bug.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the same as in [Problem with \pspicture in a simple plain TeX code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329829/problem-with-pspicture-in-a-simple-plain-tex-code)

If you look at the part labeled “The same in TeX Live 2015” in my answer, you see where the problem arises: the fact that `\overfullrule` is set to a positive value is taken as a signal that draft mode is on, so just a box is drawn.

Solution: upgrade your TeX distribution. The problem disappears with TeX Live 2016.